# Chest pain while running over 160 bpm

Tags: running, cardio, heart-rate-monitor

I've started running again after a 4 month period of inactivity due to bronchitis. Used to be a sporty guy up to five years ago (I'm 35 now) then almost nothing until last year. Last year everything was fine while I was running in the gym.

Now I've been training again for about a month, slowly building up my mileage. Now I can do 6km in 35 min but towards the end of my run when my heart-rate naturally goes up and I also start running a little faster I noticed that I get a mild but constant chest pain so I slow down and then I'm fine. As soon as I drop below 160 bpm I'm fine again. Is this something you think I should have checked?

Cheers

Comment: What kind of pain and where?  Upper/lower? Center/side?

Comment: Yes you should have it checked out by your doctor. Pain or pressure in the chest esp. during exercise may be a [warning sign](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Warning-Signs.html). Only your doctor can tell you if it is a health problem or not. The [NIH](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/health-topics/topics/heartattack/) describes chest pain or discomfort: "This involves uncomfortable pressure, squeezing, fullness, or pain in the center or left side of the chest that can be mild or strong. This discomfort or pain often lasts more than a few minutes or goes away and comes back."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most definitely have it checked.

Stress tests are one of the ways that cardiologists check for abnormalities in heart function, as the heart may exhibit dysrhythmia at that time (Under workload such as you are when running), and be perfectly normal at other times.

It may be a touch of pleurisy (inflammation of the outside lining of the lungs) from the bronchitis, or it may be something else. Any kind of chest pain should be vetted by a professional.